# Encrypt in Android, Decrypt in PHP using phpseclib

Tags: android, security, base64, rsa, phpseclib

I encrypt data in Android application and encode it to send over to php webservice.

Then I decode it and decrypt it using $rsa->decrypt(base64_decode($data));

$rsa->decrypt return false. Why is that so?

This is the code in android

```
//get private key 
String privateKeyString = "MIICWwIBAAKBgQDVIJ8H3Oszc5fWdgpwymWksF1WxkXJHIfdS6Ta1bHeqwEzPIkN f3iVk14LfaoSZpRb9Yvi/jvkXxIzJbHq6aKfnQOC6tKIiixvVvpCfxr1eV4urDdz H9RNy9bqGdXzTQdgQi+KRx0Dcy9RNsl7ZGLAGrUFRnPI4GTdH+7wm4QogQIDAQAB AoGAcUcKX7KC7HDm5h0NRY+94H/AzItLsi3Q5MT81Tc5d+EqHSJysdLrs4yFMtRS 3b7Z4dqrxDVefe4uDTNe0j3lqboKz8oKwAU+paKx3wubHb7aeQnfzwM9mPQJHgEO zBjlvbL4oEa/gklu3VohZAc1daqpPajdWuOQQp4S+jUllrECQQDrITlSjvkxt8ud /vYIcEXHew3iW4nzaAH3z4PRAGZofRpk/OusGZ6cdZoYMTZcdxYTCCbZ5eeyGukW 5QCadie1AkEA6Atx8Z0F7WhLI2lGvCGy+vIOL0vBDZSma0cvLYLAXMx8duoWQ9J2 LwT7SsnRXMeq/8wlNHL7mFEf+YFZBKKlHQJAO78kfrr/zUdjwREBWaGVyZuWKpeS FTyvi1W6rAgK/bAUXeb6x69241DqyAzxQEuuW0WuAZ5u4o39/qhQH++4JQJAAepe RW1TaDNNM3yh/dmVXabz4QYSEOeiPA55YDnNFrcFbAHgryyklxzGakaiOM7ZJYVs 5TLxyr8YsXmU34nsLQJALzC8CaFXJcnU0+6+KoKX7iq1aP3X4LgP4Gianix6pfRo aV8UHnfFLRSgPdn1ZYmKtJfnsJXJYoE+o9xEErb5EQ==";

// converts the String to a PublicKey instance
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey key = keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(privateKeyString.toString(), Base64.DEFAULT)));

// encrypts the message
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] encrpytedText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.encode(phoneUid.getBytes("CP1252"), Base64.DEFAULT));
data = new String(encrpytedText, "CP1252");
```

This is the code in php

```
include('Crypt/RSA.php');
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
//Set the encryption mode
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);

//check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['data']) {
$data= $_POST['data'];
$key =  '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDVIJ8H3Oszc5fWdgpwymWksF1W xkXJHIfdS6Ta1bHeqwEzPIkNf3iVk14LfaoSZpRb9Yvi/jvkXxIzJbHq6aKfnQOC 6tKIiixvVvpCfxr1eV4urDdzH9RNy9bqGdXzTQdgQi+KRx0Dcy9RNsl7ZGLAGrUF RnPI4GTdH+7wm4QogQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';

$rsa->loadKey($key );
$decrypted = $rsa->decrypt(base64_decode($data));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. Here is a reference for those who are doing similar thing to me. Hope that this will help other people.

In android (RSA encrypt with private key)

```
String encoded = null;
byte[] encrypted = null;
String plaintext = "...";

try {
    String privKeyPEM = "...";
    byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(privKeyPEM, Base64.DEFAULT);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decoded);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(spec);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privKey);

    encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes());
    encoded = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In PHP (decrypt with public key) (using phpseclib)

```
$publickey = '...';    
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);

//decode and decrypt
$decoded =  base64_decode($encrypted);
$rsa->loadKey($publickey);
$decrypted = $rsa->decrypt($decoded);
```

Comment: You encrypt data with a public key and decrypt data with a private key.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the right parameters to cipher.doFinal?

Quoting the [javadoc entry](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacardx/crypto/Cipher.html):

```
doFinal(byte[] inBuff, short inOffset, short inLength, byte[] outBuff, short outOffset)
```

Also, it looks like you're base64-encoding the plaintext before encryption when you should be encrypting the ciphertext after encryption?

Comment: I made some changes but it is still false
byte[] encrpytedText = cipher.doFinal(phoneUid.getBytes("CP1252");
encoded= Base64.encode(encrpytedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
data = new String(encoded, "CP1252");